# not able to fetch comment from django templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to build a social network in django. In this code I am trying to enter comments to a post through the template box in my template. But the comment is not getting fetched in my database. My code is as below:

My forms.py creates a model form for comments

**forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ('ctext',)
```

Models has a seperate comment model which has foreign keys from post model and user model.

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
text = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
imgfile = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/', blank=True, null=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date=timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
comment_auth = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
ctext = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date=timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.ctext
```

I guess the logic in views is going wrong somewhere as it been shown while debugging

**views.py**

```
def post_list(request):
posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
post = get_object_or_404(Post, title=title)
cform = CommentForm()
comments = Comment.objects.all()
if request.method == "POST":
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        new_comment.post = post
        new_comment.save()

    #cform = CommentForm(request.GET)
    #data = {}
    #Comment.ctext(**data)
    #if cform.is_valid():
    #comment={}
    #comment['ctext'] = request.POST['ctext']            
    #cform.changed_data['comment_auth'] = request.user
    #cform['comment_auth'] = request.user
    #cform['comment_auth_id_id'] = request.user

    #cform.save()

        return render(request, 'users/post_list.html', {'posts': posts, 'comments': comments, 'form': cform})
else:
    form = CommentForm()

return render(request, 'users/post_list.html', {'posts': posts, 'comments': comments, 'form': cform})
```

**Template**

```
 <div>
            <h2><a href="">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            {{image.imgfile.url}}
            {% if post.imgfile %}
                <img src="{{ post.imgfile.url }}" alt="{{ post.imgfile.url }}">
            {% endif %}
            <p>By:- {{ post.author }}</p>
            <p>published: {{ post.published_date }}</p>
            <form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/users/post/list">{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}
                {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
                    <p><b>Comments: </b></p>
                    <p><b>{{ comment.comment_auth }}: </b>{{ comment.ctext }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
                <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Comment</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: where is `title` defined ?

Comment: also move this `{% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}...{% endfor %}` outside of your form tag.

Comment: may be using variable using "comment" it is used in template tag to comment {% comment %}  {% encomment %}

Comment: @Ahtisham which title are you talking about

Comment: change this `{% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}` to `{% for comment in comments %}` and can you update your question with `Post` model

Comment: @malavshah  Is your div element under `{% for post in posts %}` ?

Comment: @Ahtisham yes it is

Comment: @MalavShah Is post being displayed ?

Comment: I was talking about this title: `title=title` in `post = get_object_or_404(Post, title=title)`. where is `title` defined ?

Comment: @Ahtisham that is what I am not getting. Where should I define it? title is a attribute in Post model and foreign key in Comment model. So how will i fetch it in views and define it??

Comment: @Ahtisham have added Post Model

Comment: @MalacShah Is `CustomUser` inheriting from `AbstractUser` class ?

Comment: @Ahtisham Yes it is. I just solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change **views.py** as follows:

```
def post_list(request):

posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
comment_form = CommentForm()

comments = Comment.objects.all()
if request.method == "POST":
    data = {
        'ctext': request.POST['ctext'],
        'comment_auth_id': request.user.id,
        'title_id': request.POST['title_id']
    }
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=data)
    if comment_form.is_valid():            
        Comment.objects.create(**data)
    return render(request, 'users/post_list.html', {
        'posts': posts, 
        'comments': comments, 
        'form': comment_form
        })
else:

    return render(request, 'users/post_list.html', {
        'posts': posts, 
        'comments': comments, 
        'form': comment_form
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

i am assuming that you have post and comment entries already trough /admin and that you are able to fetch your posts, according to your question here would be the simpliest way to fetch your post-related comments:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <div>
      {{ post.title }}
      By - {{ post.author }}
      {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
<-- is now looking up for all comment entries, where this post is the set foreignkey -->
         <p><b>Comments: </b></p>
         <p><b>{{ comment.comment_auth }}: </b>{{ comment.ctext }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'users/post_list.html', context)
```

See [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Comment: do you even have some comments in your database?

Comment: it will be used to display comments on the page. Cannot delete

Comment: Yes I do have comments they can be added from the admin side of django.

Comment: no you dont. in the template you call the comments trough {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %} not trough {% for comment in comments %}

Comment: could you edit your question and add your post model, or check, if you have set related_name? Otherwise you could try {% for comment in comments %} {% if comment.title == post.title %} <-- your comments displayed --> {% endif %} {% endfor %}

Comment: I tried  {% for comment in comments %} {% if comment.title == post.title %} <-- your comments displayed --> {% endif %} {% endfor %} but it wasnt giving the results.

Comment: added post model

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand you are trying to post a new comment and your way of doing it is totally wrong and that is the reason why you are not able to show comments. This is the right way to do:

html:

```
<p>{{ err_msg }}</p>
{% for post in posts %}
    <div>
      <!-- Other elements -->          
      <form method="POST" action="/users/post/list">{% csrf_token %}
          {{ form }}   
          <!-- Sending id of post you are commenting on -->         
          <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}">
          <button type="submit">Comment</button>
      </form>
      <p><b>Comments: </b></p>
      {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}             
         <p><b>{{ comment.comment_auth }}: </b>{{ comment.ctext }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
def post_list(request):
   posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
   # I have removed the comments.objects.all 
   # as you getting them with post.comment_set.all in your template 
   form = CommentForm()
   data = {'posts': posts, 'form': form}    
   if request.method == "POST":
       # get the id of post you are commenting on
       cur_post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
       try:
          # check if the post exists in the database.
          post = Post.objects.get(id=cur_post_id)
          comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
          if comment_form.is_valid():
             new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
             new_comment.title= post
             new_comment.comment_auth = request.user
             new_comment.save()
       except:
          data['err_msg'] = 'Post does not exist!'  
   return render(request, 'users/post_list.html', data)
```

Comment: @malavshah I don't see anything wrong with my answer but still you did not accepted it why ? besides how are you sending the `title_id` you did not mention it also what if the post you are commenting on does not exist ? your solution will definitely fail. while as mine won't.

Comment: @malavshah And if you think answering your own question and then accepting it would earn you points here on stackoverflow then you are totally wrong. It earn you nothing while as if you accept someone else answer it would earn you +2 points.